# Aggregate a daily dataframe by month using different methods (e.g. sum, mean) to a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

I need to aggregate daily data in a multiple column dataframe by month.  Each column will be aggregated differently into a new dataframe.  This is what the data looks like:

| Date | `Lahontan.Hydrologic Inflowcfs` | `Lahontan.Pool Elevationft` | `Lahontan.Surface Areaacre` | `Lahontan.Storageacre-ft` | `CarsonAtFtChurchill.Gage Inflowcfs` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1966-10-02 | 86.7 | 4123. | 2903. | 56300 | 0.1 |
| 1966-10-03 | 34.0 | 4123. | 2876. | 55510 | 0 |
| 1966-10-04 | -72.8 | 4123. | 2844. | 54570 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | 112. | 2829. | 0 |

I have been able to aggregate the data using dplyr.  Here is an example:

```
avgHI <- ddply(mdf, "month", summarise, `Lahontan.Hydrologic Inflowcfs` = mean(`Lahontan.Hydrologic Inflowcfs`)) 
totalCRInflow <- ddply(mdf, "month", summarise, `CarsonAtFtChurchill.Gage Inflowcfs` = sum(`CarsonAtFtChurchill.Gage Inflowcfs`))
etc....
```

How do I merge all of the new monthly timestep vectors into a monthly timestep dataframe for the length of the dataframe (i.e. 1960s through 2022)?

Comment: Tell us if this helps you: ```mdf %>% group_by(Yearmon = year(Date) * 100 + month(Date)) %>% 
  summarise(
    Lahontan.Hydrologic.Inflowcfs = mean(Lahontan.Hydrologic.Inflowcfs),
    CarsonAtFtChurchill.Gage.Inflowcfs = sum(CarsonAtFtChurchill.Gage.Inflowcfs))
```

Comment: This produces a single line of aggregated data versus aggregating the entire df.  Any chance to update the code to agg the entire dataframe by month?

Comment: Ok, if i understand well, you need to add new columns with the aggregates, preserving the existing number of rows. Then use `mutate` instead of `summarize` in the previous example (but preserve group_by). And of course use new column names.